# Bind scroll to on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, onclick

I've got a `downArrow` and `upArrow` buttons on my page to control scrolling.

When scrolled to the bottom of the page, the *down arrow* disappears; and the *up arrow* disappears when scrolled to the top. Everything works perfectly.

**Question:**

How do I bind the mouse wheel scroll to my on `click` function? So if a user scrolls using the mouse wheel, the arrows disappear accordingly.

```
$('#downArrow').on('click', function () { //how to bind mouse scroll?
    //scroll down
});
```

Comment: @freedomn-m: thanks. I only want to be able to detect mousewheel scroll along with the click function as I'm going to implement this when scrolled over a div.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check the scroll of the website and trigger the `click` event of `downArrow` and `upArrow` buttons depending of the scroll value. This will work.

#### Check scroll of the website:

```
// We get the $(document) —or $(window)—, because we want to check the scroll of the website. 
var $body = $(document), oldScrollValue = 0;

$body.on('scroll', function() {

    if ($body.scrollTop() > oldScrollValue ) {
          $('#downArrow').trigger('click');
    }else{
          $('#upArrow').trigger('click');
    }

    oldScrollValue = $body.scrollTop();

});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/tomloprod/has67o9r/

---

#### Check scroll of an element:

```
// We get the `$("#divID")`, because we want to check the scroll of this element. 
var $element = $("#divID"), oldScrollValue = 0;

$element.on('scroll', function() {

    if ($element.scrollTop() > oldScrollValue ) {
          $('#downArrow').trigger('click');
    }else{
          $('#upArrow').trigger('click');
    }

    oldScrollValue = $element.scrollTop();

});
```

Remember to add some `CSS` code like this, or the scroll will be of the document :

```
#divID{
   overflow:scroll;
   height:200px;
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/tomloprod/has67o9r/1/

> **ACLARATION:**
>
> I like to add an " **$** " before the name of variables which containing objects JQuery ; so I can differentiate from the objects DOM easily.

Comment: can yu briefly exaplin this `$body.bind('scroll', function() {` ? why $body ? Also `.bind` will soon be depreciated so can I replace it with `.on` ?

Comment: why trigger the click rather than just removing the arrows on the page

Comment: @Adelphia because if the user uses the mouse halfway and then continue with the arrows it would still work. that's the reason.

Comment: thanks. If I want to detect the scroll on a particular div (rather than $body), can I replace `$body` by `$('#divID')` ?

Comment: Yes, and all will work perfectly: but **remember** to add some `CSS` class like this: `#divID{  overflow:scroll; height:200px; }` Or the scroll will be of the document

Comment: Seems like you're getting up votes coz I've not closed this yet. I'll wait for a while before marking the correct answer. thanks.